# How do I output data from a text file to a JTable and have it refresh when the text file is edited?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is where the data is coming from:

```
private void btnPlaceOrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String name = txtClientName.getText();
    String address = txtClientAddress.getText();
    String date = txtDeliveryDate.getText();
    String contact = txtContactInfo.getText();
    String small = txtSmall.getText();
    String medium = txtMedium.getText();
    String large = txtLarge.getText();
    
    BufferedWriter buf;
    try{
        buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("orders.txt", true));
        buf.write(name + " " + address + " " + small + " " + medium + " " + large + " " + date + " " + contact);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Order sent");
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

How would I display the data that gets collected from this into a `JTable` that updates whenever new data is introduced to the text file?

Comment: Why not update the table at the same time as you write the data to the file. It will be more efficient then reading the entire file and recreating the table. Also, don't use an empty catch block. How will you ever know if an exception occurs?

Comment: @camickr How would I go about updating the table at the same time?

Comment: You invoke the addRow(...) method of the DefaultTableModel of your JTable.

Comment: Either you have some kind of model/manager which generates events when the state changes or you use some kind of file watcher to watch for changes to the file.  I'd lean towards the model/manager approach, as it would take responsibility for managing the contents and interactions between different parties

Comment: If you add data to the file using some kind of form, just add the new data to `TableModel` and, in addition to it, append it to the file.